# how to crop a image , resize croper frame and save it in another canvas by using angular 2 and typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html5-canvas

I want to crop upload image and crop it on canvas. the cropping frame can be editable(resize) then i want to save the cropped image in to another canvas and to save it jpg format and also and cannot use npm packages for this.

Comment: I don't think angular and typescipt was made for image cropping, but you can do it on javascript as regular.

Comment: i want to make a image cropper for a company project. it shoud be in angular 2. can any body help me..

Comment: i use angular cli project can you show me a way to put javascript on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can do it in Angular and Typescript. But you can do it on  Javascript.
You can follow this tutorial on nodehead.com. It worked for me.

https://nodehead.com/part-5-cropping-and-tiling-images-on-html-canvas/

Comment: thanks for your guidance it's very much essential to me